# cv2 in django 504 gateway timeout

Tags: python, django, opencv

opencv in my project django is very slow, and very times the url is not load and return 504 gateway timeout, and server apache2 is very slow when the url of cv is loading. Why is that?

The code does not raise any errors.

This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
import cv2
import pytesseract
import os

def get_string(imagen):
    # convert the image to a NumPy array and then read it into
    # OpenCV format
    image = numpy.asarray(bytearray(imagen.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # convert the image to grayscale and flip the foreground
    # and background to ensure foreground is now "white" and
    # the background is "black"
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

    # threshold the image, setting all foreground pixels to
    # 255 and all background pixels to 0
    thresh = cv2.threshold(
        gray, 0, 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # grab the (x, y) coordinates of all pixel values that
    # are greater than zero, then use these coordinates to
    # compute a rotated bounding box that contains all
    # coordinates
    coords = numpy.column_stack(numpy.where(thresh > 0))
    angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]

    # the `cv2.minAreaRect` function returns values in the
    # range [-90, 0); as the rectangle rotates clockwise the
    # returned angle trends to 0 -- in this special case we
    # need to add 90 degrees to the angle
    if angle < -45:
        angle = -(90 + angle)
    # otherwise, just take the inverse of the angle to make
    # it positive
    else:
        angle = -angle

    # rotate the image to deskew it
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(
        image, M, (w, h),
        flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC,
        borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

    # load the rotated image and convert it to grayscale
    gray_rotated = cv2.cvtColor(rotated, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_rotated = cv2.threshold(
        gray_rotated, 0, 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # write the rotated grayscale image to disk as a temporary file so we can
    # apply OCR to it
    filename = "/srv/archivos/prueba_{}".format(imagen.name)
    cv2.imwrite(filename, gray_rotated)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang='spa')
    os.remove(filename)
    return text
```

Thanks and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

heyyy!! the solutions is in apache2.conf add this line

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

More information in this post:
https://serverfault.com/questions/844761/wsgi-truncated-or-oversized-response-headers-received-from-daemon-process

im very happy!!!